# Rails join(includes) tables where "id" is not present in one table and different primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I have two models where one has "id" as the primary key. Second model doesn't have "id" as primary key. Instead has a composite key. How to join these?

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :B, :order => "dt DESC"
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :A, :foreign_key => :emp_id
end
```

The emp_id acts as the foreign key.
In the controller for A,

```
arel = A.includes(:b)
```

This fails.
I get following error,

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'b.id' in 'field list': SELECT  `a`.`id` AS t0_r0,....

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `primary_key` on the `belongs_to` or the `has_one`.

More info on these options can be found at,

[ActiveRecord belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

[ActiveRecord has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

Comment: Did this, still no help. Edited the post too.

Comment: Does eager loading always looks for all tables with the "id" field as manadatory?

Comment: How about setting the `self.primary_key` in the `B` model. You'll have to use the `composite_primary_keys` gem because ActiveRecord doesn't support composite keys. See https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys

Comment: Didn't require composite_primary_keys. Just specifying self.primary_key helped. Thanks.